# Cross Domain Tracking script into Google Tag Manager settings?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to set up my website to have cross domain tracking with the online store Gumroad.com, inside my Google Analytics. So that I can follow the user events from one site onto the next.
Gumroad has [instructions at this link](https://help.gumroad.com/article/175-google-analytics), but they are in the format of a script to be pasted into the site.

I use Tag Manager and am wanting to input these parameters into my Google Analytics Settings variable (which is how Google recommends doing Cross domain tracking with Tag Manager)

I'll attach the script that they provided, as well as my Google Analytics Settings variable in Tag Manager. If anyone knows how to set up the rest of the parameters that would be greatly appreciated!

Script:

```
<script>
// mystorefront.com is your site's domain.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'mystorefront.com;, {'name': 'sampleTracker', 'allowLinker': true, ';cookieDomain': 'mystorefront.com'});
ga('sampleTracker.require', 'linker');
ga('sampleTracker.linker:autoLink', ['mystorefront.com']);
ga('sampleTracker.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

My Tag Manager (Google Analytics Settings variable) setup so far:

[[image: Google Analytics variable configuration]]

Comment: Indeed those instructions are unlikely to work ! Stay tuned

Answer (score 0):

Set domains in list without protocol.

It also does not make sense that you use cookieDomain as *Field to set* when it is already defined in the field below the tracking ID.

Comment: OK I can remove the protocols. And I was thinking that may be the case about cookieDomain. I saw it as a field option as well as a built in option so I wanted to display both to get confirmation, so that makes sense.

How about the rest of the parameters like sampleTracker, autoLink etc? Do you know where/how I enter those?

Thanks for the response